# Cannot 'git push' - the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: macos, git, ssh

I have a git repository on my local machine that I push to github and a staging server, which is hosted with HostGator. I followed [this guide](http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/git/push-git-repo-into-shared-hosting-account-like-hostgator/) to setup my staging server to allow me to push to it, which has worked well in the past.

After not pushing anything for about a month, I now see this error when I try to push to the staging server (where [hostname] is replaced with my url):

```
ssh: connect to host [hostname] port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

`git remote -v` shows:

```
bright  [user]@[hostname]:[path to repo] (fetch)
bright  [user]@[hostname]:[path to repo] (push)
origin  git@github.com:[reponame.git] (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:[reponame.git] (push)
```

The relevant portion of my .git/config is as follows:

```
[remote "[remote in question"]
    url = [user]@[hostname]:[path to repo]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/[remote]/*
```

It may be worth noting that when I `ssh` into this server, I use port 2222, but as you can see from the error message, git is trying to use port 22. I think that has always been the case though, even when this was working correctly.

What steps can I take to determine why the `git push` is timing out on my staging server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may have setup port 2222 in your local `~/.ssh/config` file.  Maybe that config was replaced or removed?

Comment: my local `~/.ssh/config` specifies port 2222. I'm using a Mac and doing everything via the command line. Looks like I need to figure out how `git` decides what ssh settings to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the port in the remote definition use:

```
url = git://[user]@[host]:2222/[path_to_repo]
```

This is only possible using the above style url starting with git://.